# file:// и content:// чем отличается и как побороть exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Tags: android, contentprovider

У меня в assets лежат html файлы. Я сделал текст кликабельным и он указывает на мой html файл. Есть свой webView . и в манифесте прописано:

`activity android:name=".ui.Catalog.MyWebView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <data android:scheme="file"></data>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Я думал, если у меня есть свой webView , то я не должен прописывать это в манифесте, но без этого приложение падает. Так вот, всё работает до api 24 .  Апи выше 24 падает с таким исключением `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/www/myFile.html#9.2 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`
 Я искал по поводу этого исключения и нашел информацию о том, что с api 24 file:// не работает и нужно использовать content:// . Попробовал просто заменить ссылки на content:// и давить в манифест  `<data android:scheme="content"></data>`  , но webView не находит html.    Прежде чем начать бороться с этой ошибкой, хотелось бы понять чем отличается `file` от content, почему content предпочтительней и как я могу перейти к `content` ?

**UPD**
Ссылка у меня находится в таком виде

```
 <string name="myUri"><a href="file:///android_asset/www/myFile.html">пункт 1.1</a></string>

 Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(myUri);
        hint.setText(sp);
        hint.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Класс моего браузера.

```
 @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MyWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
        });
        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();

        webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
}
```

Я пробовал в переопределенных методах и false ставить и что только не пробовал, но что толку если дебагер не заходит в эти методы вообще..

Comment: Если всё это происходит в рамках одного приложения, то самое простое решение - передать ссылку через экстра, там она не "испортится".

Comment: Я ведь сам не кладу в intent. Я делаю textView.set(Html.fromHtml(strUri)) и делаю текст ссылки кликабельным используя что то вроде textView.set(movement.getInstance) . И по клику на текст открывается вебвью и все уже лежит в интент

Comment: Можно конечно кастомизировать спаны, но этот костыль не простой. Проще ,наверное, всё-таки изменить схему, а на принимающей стороне (`MyWebView`) вернуть ссылке схему `file` (типа того: `url = intent.getData().toString().replaceFirst("content", "file")`) и отдать в `WebView`

Comment: Я бы попробовал это сделать, но сегодня я обнаружил, что на api 24 и выше вообще не загружается класс, где я инициализирую webView . Приложение падает еще раньше. Я добавил инфу о том, как я делаю ссылки кликабельными.  Подозреваю проблемы в LinkMovementMethod , читал что это косячная штука.

Comment: я даже удалил из манифеста  все упоминания об этом классе, но ошибка вся та же

Comment: над первым shouldOverrideUrlLoading пропишите @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: @Turalllb Она происходит в момент клика по ссылке, правильно? Под капотом создаётся интент и вызывается `startActivity(...)` - вот тут система и обнаруживает "неправильный" `uri` и дальше не идёт. Если Вы измените схему, то активность запустится. Вы ведь это уже делали: _но webView не находит html_ И тут мы меняем обратно на файл и вебвью всё найдёт.

Comment: TimurVI, это пишут когда метод устаревший и IDE начинает подсчечивать код, эта аннотация только убирает подсветку, говоря системе что я в курсе что это устарело . Не более того. И что интересно когда я переопределяю этот метод, то он зачеркнут, но после студия его не подсвечивает как устаревший. Странно

Comment: woesss, да это происходит в момент клика по ссылке. Под капотом происходит intent.setData, а исключение на getData,  но getData написана в классе где инициализируется webView , но еще url приходит в shouldOverrideUrlLoading .  ну да ладно, где то под капотом вызывается.. Я понял, что вы говорите, сейчас в классе где вебВью инициализирую я приму uri и и вновь установлю file . Сейчас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Система должна сравнить `uri` с фильтрами всех активностей, чтобы выбрать подходящие, она и вызывает для этого `getData()`

Comment: понял, в общем работает)  Спасибо) Выходит это проблема sdk , что они не продумали, ситуацию когда файл лежит в пределах моего процесса? тут есть статья по теме, надо прочитать https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Answer (score 0):

`file://` это путь к конкретному файлу

`content://` здесь не существовует "Путь к файлу" так как [не требуется чтобы содержимое хранилось как файл.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40361648/5330439)  URI контента представляет собой URI, который определяет данные в [поставщике](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics?hl=ru).

> Поставщик контента управляет доступом к центральному репозиторию
>   данных. Поставщик является компонентом приложения Android, который
>   зачастую имеет собственный пользовательский интерфейс для работы с
>   данными. Однако поставщики контента предназначены в первую очередь для
>   использования другими приложениями, которые получают доступ к
>   поставщику посредством клиентского объекта поставщика. Вместе
>   поставщики и клиенты поставщиков обеспечивают согласованный,
>   стандартный интерфейс к данным, который также обрабатывает
>   взаимодействие между процессами и обеспечивает защищенный доступ к
>   данным.

В вашем случае, как я понимаю, обмен файлами `.html` между приложениями не предполагается. Попробуйте воспользоваться следующими советами [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576567/on-clicking-the-hyperlink-in-webview-the-app-crashes-i-have-paced-all-the-html/40753538#comment68388671_40576567) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006653/5330439). [Вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484074/is-shouldoverrideurlloading-really-deprecated-what-can-i-use-instead) по теме.

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос информацией о том , как я делаю кликабельные TextView.  Я пробовал все решения, ссылки на которые вы дали и которые находил я . Везде одно и то же, все рекомендуют переопределить WebViewClient . Но у меня ничего не менялось.  А сейчас я попробовал в дебагере проверить, куда же идут вызовы. Оказалось что активность, где инициализируется webView даже не запускается. Падает исключение куда раньше. Т.е. всё описанные методы решения, не подходят в данном случае. Апи ниже 24 доходит до запуска ..

Comment: TimurVI, да обмен между приложениями не предполагается, но когда я кликаю по ссылке, на апи 23 предлагается выбрать приложение для записука. А на апи 24 уже падает.  Дело в том, что я переопределил методы webView , сейчас прикреплю как я их переопределил, но проверка дебагером на апи 23 и 16 , где приложение работает, показывает что приложение не использует переопределенные методы. Я добавлю кода в вопрос.

Comment: Такое ощущение что когда я делаю setWebViewClient его методы не срабатывают, потому что по умолчанию срабатывает другой клиент.  Читал что в андроид этот клиент менялся, в итоге используют Cromium что ли..

Comment: `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` нужен для настройки открытия ссылок на странице, уже загруженной в вебвью.

Comment: да..не знал..Т.е. получается что при первом открытии, я никак не могу переопределить поведение и заставить по умолчанию выбирать мой webView ?

Comment: думаю возможно это сделать, потому что у меня установлено приложение, которое при первом клике не вызывает Окно выбора браузеров

Comment: Похоже для этого я должен реализовать кастомный ClickableSpan

Comment: Нужен уникальный интент, на который откликнется только Ваша активность, например применить в адресе кастомную схему, хост, что-то ещё. А лучше явный интент (с указанием класса активности) - есть идея переопределить `startActivity(Intent)`, где проверить интент (если у Вас может запускаться не одна активность), добавить к нему класс: `intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MyWebView.class);` и вызвать супер.

Comment: насчет кастомной схемы понял. А где же мне интент переопределить, я ведь использую Html.fromHtml и как вы сами сказали , под капотом вызывается 'startActivity'